# How to pass intent to ask user to chose any app to scan QR code?

Tags: android, android-intent, barcode-scanner, qr-code

I am making a android app which requires QR code scanning and then parsing the text as a resul. I would like to pass intent to other apllications like google goggles or Barcode scanner which can do the job efficiently and  take the scanned text back as result of the intent.

I have read the other questions out there for the same and found that i can do it with Zxing library also, but i would like this functionality to be handled by other pre-installed app.

So could someone help me with the way we will pass intent in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent